# adding the libpng library to cpp in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have never added libraries before and I couldn't find a tutorial which I understood and could follow. I downloaded libpng from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/) in "download latest version". could anyone explain to me what goes where with specific names and how to find everything? much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could follow the following steps:

1,Add the path to the header file to the Additional Include Directories(property - >c/c++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories)

2,Add the path to the .lib file to the Additional Library Directories (property -> linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories)

3,Add the name of the .lib file with its extension to Additional Dependencies (property -> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies)

I suggest you could try to NuGet to install libpng.

1，Right click the project and choose `Manage NuGet Packages`

[image]

2,Browse -> libpng, and then click installer.

[image]

3,path to the .lib file:`...\packages\libpng.1.6.28.1\build\native\lib\x64\v140\dynamic\Debug`

After adding libpng to the VS2019 C++ project through Nuget, because the Nuget package version is suitable for v140, I suggest you can download and install `msvc v140` through visual studio installer.

[image]

And then right-click on the project Properties-->Configuration Properties-->General--> change Platfrom Toolset to Visual Studio 2015(v140).

[image]

And you could also install [libpng-v142 nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libpng-v142/1.6.37.2?_src=template) instead and it is for VS2019 VC++.

Comment: I added the link which I dowloaded libpng from because I couldn't find the right .lib and .dll files there, could you look at it and explain to me like I'm 5?

Comment: @Itay123 I have edited my answer, please check.

Comment: only part I'm not too sure about is downloading and installing msvc through visual studio installer. so it would be nice of you to edit it just one more time.

besides that you were really helpful and I appreciate your dedication.

Comment: @Itay123 The nuget package downloaded directly through visual studio 2019 is only applicable to the v140 platform. However, the platform toolset of visual studio 2019 is v142. So we need to install the v140 version of the platform toolset.